# wordpress Shortocode running twice?

Tags: plugins, functions, shortcode

I developed a plugin for my citrus payment gateway.I created a **shortcode** to manage it. It was running absolutely fine some days ago.Now I don't know who changed what, now that **shortcode** is running twice :(

This is my code I am using.

```
add_shortcode('citrusafterpayment', 'citrusafterpayment_function');

function citrusafterpayment_function()
{

    mail('test.gupta@test.com','check-in','asd');
    global $wpdb;
    if(isset($_REQUEST['TxStatus']) && $_REQUEST['TxStatus'] != '')
    {
       if($TxStatus == 'CANCELED')
        {
           $return_msg = '<div class="row-fluid"><div class="span12"> <div class="error">You have canceled your transaction.</div></div></div>';
          return $return_msg;
        }
    }
}
```

I am using this shortcode on one of my webpage. Whenever that page is hitting I am getting emails two times.

I googled it but there is no useful result.

Please help me.

Comment: in the page make sure you close the shortcode eg: [citrusafterpayment][/citrusafterpayment]

Comment: @TouqeerShafi yes it is closed fine. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, it's not the proper way to figure it out but it will solve your problem.

```
function citrusafterpayment_function()
{
    static $calls = 0;

    if($calls == 0){ $calls++;
       mail('test.gupta@test.com','check-in','asd');
       global $wpdb;
       if(isset($_REQUEST['TxStatus']) && $_REQUEST['TxStatus'] != '')
       {
           if($_REQUEST['TxStatus'] == 'CANCELED')
           {
           $return_msg = '<div class="row-fluid"><div class="span12"> <div class="error">You have canceled your transaction.</div></div></div>';
          return $return_msg;
           }
       }  
    }


}
```

**Edited:**

You should pass: `$_REQUEST['TxStatus']` in the if statement `$TxStatus` is not defined in the function.

Comment: NO. It did not solve it. still getting emails two times :(

Comment: I think you changed code. and yes now email is coming once but now another issue comes up that the message which I was returning not printing on my webpage

Comment: Are you sure that `$_REQUEST['TxStatus']` are you getting ?

Comment: 100% sure. Code under function is working fine. I have tested it so many times.